# Is it true if I use {{post.get_image_url}} over {{post.image.url}}, my web is in security danger?

Tags: python, django

So, I made a similar post a few days ago. And the reason I am asking this more specific question is because I got a reply back from my django tutorial instructor that says 
if I do

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
and then in template, 
<img src='{{category.get_image_url}}' class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="210" height="200" style="text-align:center;"/>
```

I would have security hole.and I shouldn't serve static or media files from the Django server.

But if I do

{{category.image.url}} I get an error sometimes. 
I'm using s3 amazon storage, and put my static folder seperated. 
Do I have to change the way I get image like {{category.image.url}}?

Comment: `{{category.image.url}} I get an error sometimes`, which type of error? is the image properly uploaded to cloud bucket or aws?

Comment: What solution are you using for S3?

Comment: Your instructor is probably talking about the security concern mentioned in the [docs for MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-url)

Comment: @Sayse but that security concern has no bearing on whether OP uses `image.url` or his own method to link to the files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Sure, but as far as I can tell, it wasn't the instructor that recommended using `image.url`. As I have read it, they just mentioned a "security hole". Of course I could be missing details from the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As I told you in the previous question, your `get_image_url` is doing *exactly the same* as `image.url` would do. So there can't possibly be a "security hole" here.

Where you serve your images from is up to you; Django won't serve them itself in production, but that's not to say you can't serve them from the same machine. But whichever you do, `settings.MEDIA_URL` should be set to point to that location; so, again, your method does nothing that `image.url` does not do.

Comment: I knew it, it's just my instructor said I shouldn't do it like the way I do it. so I had to make sure...

Comment: I will delete this question, since it duplicates from the other question I made